# Customizing IPython notebook / Jupyter slide show

Tags: jupyter-notebook, reveal.js, jupyter

I created a slideshow using the slideshow feature of IPython notebook / Jupyter, which works fine. I created and hosted the slides via `ipython nbconvert ...` which works fine too. But I cannot find any information how to customize the slides. Obviously I have to customize `Reveal.js` which is not very well documented too.

Can somebody give a starting point on how to get some copyright, logo, ... in the header/footer of my presentation?

Comment: You could start looking [here](https://github.com/e-gor/Reveal.js-Title-Footer).

Answer (score 4):

`Reveal.js` is really just a web template. If you want to customize it further, CSS/Javascript knowledge will be required.

A straightforward way to define header/footer is to change the CSS

```
.slides .header{
  position:absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
}
.slides .footer{
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: -50%;
}
```

You can then insert your footer contents

```
<div class="footer">
   <p>Copyright ACME Incorporated ©2016</p>
</div>
```