# How to increase the page width in ipython notebook (jupyter) slides

Tags: jupyter-notebook, reveal.js, nbconvert

In an ipython notebook (jupyter) slideshow created with

```
ipython nbconvert presentation.ipynb --to slides --post serve
```

images are of poor quality because they seem to be scaled down to the page width. How can I increase the page width / display larger images in the presentation?

I found a partial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33420079/customizing-ipython-notebook-jupyter-slide-show) but this requires doing the "--post serve" part manually which I can find no documentation for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a long search I found the answer myself :

1. Copy template file from

   `lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbconvert/templates/html/slides_reveal.tpl`

   to the directory of the notebook.
2. Customize it, for example, in `Reveal.initialize({ })` add

   ```
   width: '80%',
   height: '100%',
   transition: 'concave',
   ```
3. Run

   ```
   jupyter nbconvert presentation.ipynb --to slides --template slides_reveal.tpl --post serve
   ```

   or just

   ```
   jupyter nbconvert presentation.ipynb --to slides --template slides_reveal.tpl
   ```

   then open `presentation.slides.html` directly in the browser. Alternatively:

   ```
   python -m SimpleHTTPServer
   ```

   and navigate the browser to

   ```
   http://127.0.0.1:8000/presentation.slides.html
   ```

Comment: Really cool! It took me a long time to figure out where the problem is - and finally you provided the (only one - as far as I know) solution! Many thanks!